# Find out the number of integer solution of $[\frac{x}{100}[\frac{x}{100}]]=5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Find out the number of integer solution of $[\frac{x}{100}[\frac{x}{100}]]=5$
My Attempt
let $x=100k+t$ where $0 \leq t \leq 99$ and $k>=0$. Thus $[\frac{x}{100}]=k$. Hence   $[\frac{x}{100}k]=5$ thus   $\frac{x}{100}k=5+ r$ where $0 \leq r < 1$
From this point I am stuck what to do. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this non-decreasing?  Find the lowest $x$ and the greatest $x$ that satisfy the condition, and everything else in between will work too, won't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with $y=x/100$ first.  [y [y]]=5.  We know $ [y][y]\le [y [y]]=5\le y [y]<([y]+1)[y] $.  From that we can see $[y]^2 \le 5 <[y]^2+[y] $.

From this we can conclude $[y] =2$.

And from there it solves itself.

$[y [y]]=[2y]=5$

$5 \le 2y < 5+1$

$5/2\le y < 3$

$5/2 \le x/100 <3$

$250\le x < 300$